# Creating a table from a query in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and I'm trying to create a table from a query. However, I'm running into some errors when I try to execute the query.

I'm trying to create a table called `"CUM_PRD"` with the following columns:

```
Gov_fld_nm,
Gov_pol_nm,
Oil_pd,
Gas_pd,
Water_pd.
```

The values that should be populated with this query is from the query below.

```
SELECT GOV_FLD_NM,
SUM (OIL_PD),
SUM (GAS_PD),
SUM (WAT_PD)
FROM PRE_PRD
GROUP BY GOV_FLD_NM
```

This query works fine when it is all by itself, but when I try to include it in the create table query, it does not work. I believe I'm not using the correct syntax.

Could someone help?

This is what I tried to use.

```
CREATE TABLE CUM_PRD
(
    GOV_FLD_NM NVARCHAR (50),
    OIL_PD INT,
    GAS_PD INT,
    WAT_PD INT
)
INSERT INTO CUM_PRD
SELECT (
    GOV_FLD_NM,
    SUM (OIL_PD),
    SUM (GAS_PD),
    SUM (WAT_PD)
)
FROM PRE_PRD
GROUP BY GOV_FLD_NM
```

Comment: Please use a code block for readability

Comment: What database are you using?  Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle,...?  Your syntax is only slightly off... the CREATE and INSERT statements are separate, so must be separated by a semicolon.  I think someone has already posted an answer with the correct INSERT INTO syntax, but you're very close.  Some databases have variants such as 'CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...' that may be helpful.

Comment: When you specify which db you use, please also add a tag for that db

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a temp table you can use `SELECT ... INTO...`:

```
SELECT GOV_FLD_NM, SUM (OIL_PD), SUM (GAS_PD), SUM (WAT_PD) 
INTO #CUM_PRD
FROM PRE_PRD 
GROUP BY GOV_FLD_NM
```

Since your script is not creating a temp table why not just create the table first, then insert into it:

```
CREATE TABLE CUM_PRD 
( 
  GOV_FLD_NM NVARCHAR (50), 
  OIL_PD INT,
  GAS_PD INT, 
  WAT_PD INT 
);
```

Then insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO CUM_PRD (GOV_FLD_NM, OIL_PD, GAS_PD, WAT_PD)
SELECT GOV_FLD_NM, SUM (OIL_PD), SUM (GAS_PD), SUM (WAT_PD) 
FROM PRE_PRD 
GROUP BY GOV_FLD_NM
```

Comment: @user1949277 Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow, if this answer is helpful to you then be sure to accept it via the checkmark to the left of it. It will help future visitors and you will get site reputation for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do

```
SELECT GOV_FLD_NM, SUM (OIL_PD), SUM (GAS_PD), SUM (WAT_PD) 
INTO CUM_PRD 
FROM PRE_PRD 
GROUP BY GOV_FLD_NM;
```

SELECT INTO creates a table for you

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CREATE TABLE table_name AS syntax

```
CREATE TABLE CUM_PRD
AS
(
SELECT GOV_FLD_NM, SUM (OIL_PD) OIL_PD_SUM, SUM (GAS_PD) GAS_PD_SUM, SUM (WAT_PD) WAT_PD_SUM
FROM PRE_PRD
GROUP BY GOV_FLD_NM)
```